# VirtualHosts not working properly

Tags: apache2, webserver, virtualhost

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, I apt-get installed apache2, php and mysql. From there, `localhost` was working fine, running from the `/var/www/html/` directory.

I created a new file, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.example.conf`, and mimicked the `000-default.conf` file that already existed in that folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      laravel.example
    ServerAlias     www.laravel.example
    ServerAdmin tomjhash@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/laravel.example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel.example_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel.example_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I created the folder at `/var/www/sites/laravel.example`, added in `127.0.0.1 laravel.example` to `/etc/hosts`, ran `a2ensite laravel.example.conf`, restarted apache, but still just get Web page not available when I try load it. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is a permissions problem. what are the ownership and permissions if the directory and files?

Comment: Have you tried doing `http://laravel.example/` in your web browser?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen bingo. just fixed it after i asked after chown and chmodding the /var/www/ directories

Comment: Close-voter(s): Questions are only off-topic as "a problem that can't be reproduced" when they went away and there is no real solution known. Here, [the OP has self-answered with a solution that may help others](http://askubuntu.com/a/518175/22949).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set ownership / permissions of the directories and files to e readable by www-data

Personally I use:

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www
chmod 750 /var/www/sites
chmod 750 /var/www/sites/sites/laravel.example
chmod 640 /var/www/sites/sites/laravel.example/*
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [my comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518170/virtualhosts-not-working-properly?noredirect=1#comment703747_518170), I fixed this issue by `chown`ing the /var/www/ directory recursively to my current user, and chmodding the directory to 755, restarted and it seemed to be working, so hopefully this was the actual fix.